# Pycharm cant create a new Project (Windows10)

Tags: python, proxy, pycharm, anaconda, pyqt5

So, i have a problem with Creating a new Pycharm Project.
When i try to create a new Project (with any interpreter and any environment) i get to the screen "Creating environment" with the loading animation. From here on nothing happens. Only when i try to create an anaconda3 project i get the following error message:

> Executed command: C:\Users\ZehentbauerP\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
> create -p C:\Users\ZehentbauerP\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject5 -y
> python=3.8
>
> Error occured: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
> https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
>
> Command output: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json):
> ...working... failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
> https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
> Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
> are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
> 'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'

Furthermore, when i go to "File -> settings -> python Interpreter -> Install" there is nothing shown. I need to add PyQt5 and qtpy to work with QT in Pycharm

Maybe a Problem: i have no full Admin rights on this device.

My attempts so far:
reinstalling pycharm => no effect
as i need a special proxy, i have "File -> Appearance & behavior _> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy"
on either auto-detect proxy settings or a manual proxy configuration. Both of them can establish a connection in the "Check connection" field.

So my final Question is: Is there a solution to that issue?

Edit:

Changing the virtual Environment gives an Error:
"WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,s..."

Waiting for like 30 minutes (until all retry's are over) gives an new Error:
"ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools"

After waiting for this it "works" (more or less) for this project.

Also, whenever i start PyCharm there is a warning in bottom right corner:
"External file changes sync may be slow Project files cannot be watched (are they under network mount?)"

Comment: Did you install python and add to path.

Comment: yes i did, i can run python with for example idle or in cmd, also existing old projects in pycharm, just no new ones

Comment: Did you install python with anaconda or from the exe file of the official website

Comment: both from python.org and anaconda. Neither of the python.exe work in pycharm (also none of the pythonw.exe)

Comment: You might have selected install python addons or python associations during the installation. Try to reinstall and make sure the installer is run in admin mode. This time don't change anything and just let the installer run in default settings.

Comment: so, when i wait for like an eternity, i can create a new project (with old pycharm). As administrator i dont have access to a necessary directory unfortunately

Comment: I never saw this error with pycharm, this is new to me. Did you try adding python to pycharm manually.

Comment: if you mean by file -> settings -> python interpreter -> add -> system interpreter i did. I think it has something to do with the permissions on this device.

Comment: K try this then, if you installed `pip`, run this command `pip install pyopenssl`, there might be `ssl` issues. If still the error persists and you have `anaconda` installed, run this command, `conda activate concerned_env`. This should work if you have `ssl` issues or `conda env` connection issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I talked with the admin of this network. He said that our proxy blocks all attempts of python downloading stuff. He will take a look if he can allow it. My Workaround is Visual Studio Code which can somehow access necessary modules anyway.

Comment: Yeah proxy can mess with us sometimes, but if you are using Vs Code for python I'll recommend Kite extension for it. It's amazing I use it with both Pycharm and VsCode for python.